# Laravel validation: exclude size check when field not required

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have validation in Laravel application, but I can't seem to make it work.

I am making validation on `Supplier` model not request.

```
public function requestOpening(Supplier $supplier)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($supplier->toArray(), $this->fullValidationRules());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect("open-new/supplier/{$supplier->id}")
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I want `hfm_code` to be required only when `is_hfm == 1`. I tried both:

```
'hfm_code' => 'size:6|exclude_if:is_hfm,0',
```

and

```
'hfm_code' => 'size:6|required_if:is_hfm,1',
```

In both scenarios I get validation error:

> The hfm code must be 6 characters.

How do I ignore size check when `is_hfm == 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order seems to matter here:

```
'hfm_code' => 'exclude_if:is_hfm,0|size:6'
```

should work. I *think* this is because it evaluates rules in order and will ignore the remaining ones if `exclude_if` passes

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Didn't think that order matters as `'hfm_code' => 'size:6|required_with:is_hfm'` was valid when validating request